# How to apply list of values to a list of functions

Tags: functions, evaluation, list-manipulation

I have the following:

```
first= {1+a,2+a,3+a,4+a}
```

and a list

```
t={0,1,2,3}
```

I want to evaluate the first element of "first" at the first element of "t" (plug in "a" the first element of "t"), then the second element of "first" evaluated at the second element of "t" and so on. Finally, I want to plot the result in the y axis against the list "t" in the x axis. How can I do this? I have tried using Table, Do, and Function Map but I cant figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
first = {1 + a, 2 + a, 3 + a, 4 + a};
t = {0, 1, 2, 3};
MapThread[#1 /. a -> #2 &, {first, t}]
(* {1, 3, 5, 7}*)
```

or

```
#[[1]] /. a -> #[[2]] & /@ Transpose@{first, t}
(* {1, 3, 5, 7}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = ReplacePart[first, Thread[Rule[Position[first, a], t]]]
ListPlot[Transpose[{t, result}]]
```